# Move unique values across different dimensions

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy

I have a requirement where I want to convert a 2D matrix to 3D by separating 3 unique values across 3 dimensions. 
For Example:
convert

```
A = [1  2  3  3
     1  1  2  1
     3  2  2  3
     1  3  3  2]
```

to

```
A = [[1  0  0  0
      1  1  0  1
      0  0  0  0
      1  0  0  0]

     [0  1  0  0
      0  0  1  0
      0  1  1  0
      0  0  0  1]

     [0  0  1  1
      0  0  0  0
      1  0  0  1
      0  1  1  0]]
```

Pardon me if the syntax of matrix representation is not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) with `outer-equality` for a vectorized solution -

```
# Input array
In [8]: A
Out[8]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 3],
       [1, 1, 2, 1],
       [3, 2, 2, 3],
       [1, 3, 3, 2]])

In [11]: np.equal.outer(np.unique(A),A).view('i1')
Out[11]: 
array([[[1, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1]],

       [[0, 0, 1, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 1, 1, 0]]], dtype=int8)
```

To use the explicit `dimension-extension` + `comparison`, it would be :

```
(A == np.unique(A)[:,None,None]).view('i1')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`np.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.1/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) and take advantage of boolean arrays and cast them to int using [`numpy.ndarray.astype`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html).

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([[1, 2, 3, 3], [1, 1, 2, 1], [3, 2, 2, 3], [1, 3, 3, 2]])

[a==i.astype(int) for i in np.unique(a)]
```

---

Output:

```
[array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 0]]), 
 array([[0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1]]), 
 array([[0, 0, 1, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 1, 1, 0]])]
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: [Ch3steR's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60788991/791430) is better

```
A = np.array([[1,2,3,3], [1,1,2,1], [3,2,2,3], [1,3,3,2]])

unique_values = np.unique(A)

B = np.array([np.zeros_like(A) for i in range(len(unique_values))])

for idx, value in enumerate(unique_values):
    B[idx][A == value] = 1
```